# Garbage characteres after reading file with random generated data

Tags: server

I'm using Ubuntu Server version 22.04.

I created a file with random data using:

```
head -c 100M </dev/urandom >random.txt
```

Next I read the file with:
more random.txt
I get this:
[image: Text]

I can see the random data inside the file.

I exit from "more" and the console now is garbled with weird characters:
[image: Text]

I have to reboot to get the normal console back.

Why this happens and how can I recover the normal console without rebooting?

Comment: don't cat files that were generated by `/dev/urandom` - that solves your problem.  `/dev/urandom` generates **random bytes* that do random things to consoles, terminals, etc. and you should NEVER cat those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "reset" command.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).